# Current 12 Months vs Previous 12 Months Sales - Rolling

Tags: sql, rolling-computation

I am still new in SQL

My Table
Columns: InDate, Sales

I want to compare rolling 12 months from TODAY to PAST 12 MONTHS Sales

What I need:

```
Current Month | Sale |  Past Month | Sale
Nov           | $550 |  Nov         | $450
```

I can get current 12 rolling months using this query:

```
SELECT SO_VInv.InvDate
FROM SO_VInv
where SO_VInv.InvDate >= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())
```

I can get current 24 rolling months using this query:

```
SELECT SO_VInv.InvDate
FROM SO_VInv
where SO_VInv.InvDate >= DATEADD(month, -24, GETDATE())
```

But I dont know how to get past rolling 12 months e.g. 2/11/2017 till 2/11/2018 as rolling past 12 months and not with fixed date.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data would also help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one row per month, use window functions:

```
SELECT i.InvDate,
       i.sale,
       SUM(i.sale) OVER (ORDER BY i.InvDate
                         ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                        ) as sales_rolling_12
FROM SO_VInv i;
```

Comment: Thanks, no I have many sales in a month. I want to sum and compare sales by month over 12 months and over past 12 months